# Serilog RollingFile path issue in MAC OS/Linux

Tags: .net, devops, serilog, core-api

I'm using a SeriLog rolling file logger in a .NET Core API (v2.2).
There is a folder called 'logs' at the root directory on my macbook (/logs).I've given read, write and execute permission for all users to this folder(it's a short-lived dev environment).  However, the log file isn't getting written to there (/logs) - it gets written within the project folder instead. what am I doing wrong...

At present, am reading the configuration for the SeriLog logger from the appsettings.json file and the configuration is as follows:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": "Information",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "RollingFile",
        "Args": {
          "path": "/logs",
          "pathFormat": "log-{Date}.txt",
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz [{Level}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",
          "fileSizeLimitBytes": 10485760,
          "rollOnFileSizeLimit": true,
          "retainedFileCountLimit": 3

        }
      }
    ],
    "Properties": {
      "Application": "QueryApi"
    }
  }
}
```